# Add custom functionality to UITextField, UILabel, UIView custom classes

Tags: ios, swift3

In my app I have some interface elements such as :`CustomLabel, CustomView, CustomTextField` (all are custom classes inherit from their base class: `UIView, UILabel, UITextField`.
At this moment I'm calling from each element `DrawRect` callback to a function that draws underline on itself and basically I have chunks of duplicated code on each subclass.
How can I make this three subclasses have the same `DrawRect` content without creating an `extension` of `UIView` because I don't want each `View` or `subclass` of `UIView` to have this behaviour.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't since `UIView` is the common superclass

Comment: Got it... So what will be the correct way to manage this?

Comment: will look into that, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you could use a protocol and a protocol extension to add your common methods to your subclasses. Then you'd only have to make your classes conform to that protocol and override drawRect to call the methods from your protocol. Adding the new behaviour by just conforming to the protocol and not doing any other changes is not possible, unfortunately. You can't override methods in protocol extensions, and you can't add methods that use the Objective-C runtime there either which would allow method swizzling.

In code this would look something like this:

```
protocol CustomDrawing {}

extension CustomDrawing where Self: UIView {
   func myDrawingCode() {
      // Whatever
   }
}
```

You use it like this then:

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel, CustomDrawing {
   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
      super.draw(rect)
      myDrawingCode()
   }
}
```

If you need to access some common property or method in `myDrawingCode()` you will have to declare them inside the CustomDrawing protocol. UIView methods are available since the protocol extension is constrained to UIView and subtypes.